# How to get the id of previous ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with 4 seperate lists, I need to know the id of the list before the one i click on.

So lets say i click on ul2 i need an alert of ul1 id.

currently im getting the clicked id with:

```
  var clicked_id = this.id;
```

and ive tried the following to get the above ul

```
  var div_id2 = $(this).parents(".divtest").next(".ultest").attr("id");
  var div_id = $(this).closest('ul').find('.ultest').attr('id');
  var x = $(this).prev().attr('id');
```

simplification of layout:

```
  <div id="doesnt matter" class="divtest">
    <ul id="ul1" class="ultest">
      <li id="doesnt matter"></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul2" class="ultest">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul3" class="ultest">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul4" class="ultest">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why would you want that? And what if you click on the first one? Just out of curiosity, what are you building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```js
$('ul').click(function() {
  let prev = $(this).prev('ul')
  console.log(prev.attr('id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="doesnt matter" class="divtest">
  <ul id="ul1" class="ultest">
    <li id="doesnt matter">item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul2" class="ultest">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul3" class="ultest">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul4" class="ultest">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: doing this i get undefined as a result, if i just print the prev object i get jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]

Comment: @RathBaloth You get undefined if you click the first list (since there is no other previous list)

Comment: what youve suggested seems to get the id of the ul from the li, im not interest in the li. i want to click anywhere on the ul and get the id of the ul above it. which is why im getting undefined. i had to console.log(prev.prevObject.attr('id')) to get it to show the id and in mycase it was liting the id if the div

Comment: @RathBaloth I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Oh sorry, i've apparently completly misunderstood what im even trying to do. i do want the previous li not the ul. rewriting this so many times has thrown me so far off track .